# Registering DLL Issue

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dll

Alright, I've got a DLL that I need to register onto Windows Server 2012 R2. The DLL itself was custom made for us and I don't know the background, but we've never had an issue like this.

Whenever I try to register the DLL, I get the error message "The module was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80004005". All the solutions say that running CMD as Administrator solves the problem. I've tried that on the Domain Administrator account, and the local Administrator account on that server, and I've even tried registering the DLL with PowerShell (as admin).

We've tried disabling UAC, that didn't help. I closed the only AV they have on the server, that didn't resolve it either.

Comment: In recent versions of Windows, "running as administrator" doesn't mean simply running under an account with administrative privileges; you must right-click on the Command Prompt icon and select "Run As Administrator" from the menu. You will be prompted for credentials; supply correct ones.

Comment: Yep, that's what I've been doing.

Comment: OK, wasn't clear from your posting.

Comment: Have you tried both `c:\Windows\System32\regsvr32 szYourDLLName.DLL` and `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 szYourDLLName.DLL` ???  Please feed back @Fabby after trying as it might be a 64-bit DLL being called by the 32 bit regsvr32version or vice versa (hard to tell with the information you gave)